# How to implement level-player collisions resolution?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, mathematics, geometry

I want to create simple collision response system (physical simulation is not required now). It is needed just that player can't go through walls.

I consider some variants: 
- Just create a set of primitive colliders (like AABB, OBB, Spheres) and check collisions in every frame (this approach is impemented now)
- Create a BVH for the big level mesh and check collisions with small set of triangles.
- Combine these two approaches and use BVH for determine which colliders I need to check.

But, probably, these variants are wrong. What algorithms and appoaches would you advice for this purpose?

Comment: What specifically is "wrong" about the approach you've described? It sounds like a rough outline of every physics engine I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, collisions that involve concave meshes sooner or later gets you in a mess.

If I were you, I would keep your current approach of tests that involve convex shapes: there is no ambiguity about inside/outside, and no nasty stuff like self intersecting meshes.

Just make it so that everything in your world has two representations: a visual model that can be as fancy, and as concave as you like.

The other representation for collisions, which is purely a collection of convex shapes, and only roughly follows the object's shape.

As an example: the visual model of an exquisite Edwardian table could be 4000 triangles. But it's physics shape is just 5 boxes.

The worst thing you could do is collide an arbitrary mesh against another arbitrary mesh. It's wasteful, and leads to horrible collision responses.

One more note: Convex dynamic objects against a static concave terrain mesh is often acceptable though. But if your terrain is a bunch of rooms that can adequately be described with boxes, I wouldn't even do that.